# Char length in Arduino sketch

Tags: c, char, arduino

I have the following `char` inside an Arduino sketch:

```
char inData[80];
```

When I print to the serial console:

```
Serial.print(strlen(inData) - 1);
```

I'm expecting to see: **79** instead I see: **655356553501234567**

Can someone shed some light as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strlen` is looking for a terminating nul. Calling it on an uninitialized array or pointer results in undefined behavior. You want `sizeof(inData)` instead.